# Time as a covariate in linear regression predicting prices

Tags: regression, time-series

This is a somewhat broad question that I encountered at work the other day.

I am trying to fit a linear regression to predict prices depending on several covariates. The observations are collected over time and I can spot a clear seasonality (higher prices in certain months and on certain days of the week). I tried to group the covariates depending on these two time-dependent factors. The fitted model was decent, but unfortunately there is a clear trend in the residuals. They tend to be above zero for some months and below zero for others.

Do I have to go for time series models now? Are there other ways to include seasonal trends in a linear regression, and how would my model diagnostics and inference change?

Comment: First-differencing your data might be one option. More typically, including the lags of the dependent variable as a regressor is another option to avoid "spurious regression" with non-stationary data. If you have panel data, then adding a time fixed-effect could work, but suffers from Nickell bias with small T/large N panels.

Comment: A step before time series may be trying to model the temporal component with some sort of periodic basis function.  Why not use a few features from a fourier series?